# Add a featured image in my theme?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I'd like to add a Featured image to a default article or a Custom Type Post in my theme but I don't get the area of the highlight image, why? In the default theme the option is present but not in my theme, what have I missed?

Comment: Do you mean the Featured Image?

Comment: yes sorry, I have the Italian version!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add theme support in the `functions.php` file of your active theme like this:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
}
```

To enable it within a custom post type, you will need to do so when registering your post type with the `supports` argument, so you'll need to add something to your already existing code that registers your post type like so (this is an example):

```
$args = array(
  'labels' => $labels,
  'public' => true,
  'publicly_queryable' => true,
  'show_ui' => true, 
  'show_in_menu' => true, 
  'query_var' => true,
  'rewrite' => true,
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'has_archive' => true, 
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'menu_position' => null,
  'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
); 
register_post_type('book',$args);
```

If you see the last line of the `$args` array, there's `thumbnail` in the `supports` array. That enables it for the custom post type.

See the Codex for more information:

For **adding thumbnail support**: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

For **registering post types**: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Or more specifically, a complete example with thumbnails added to a custom post type is here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=Function_Reference/register_post_type&oldid=112358#Example

Comment: And once you have added theme support, you must also add thumbnails to a custom post type when registering it, in the 'supports' parameter http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments

Comment: Just updated my answer with this info. :)

Comment: good explanation!